# What is signified by the yellow triangle with a black exclamation mark on Samsung devices

Tags: samsung, charging

My friend has a Samsung Galaxy S9.
Every now and then it refuses to charge because of moisture being detected in the port.

However, upon completely discharging, once, it showed a ⚠️ mark when the charger was inserted. Eventually the device started charging normally.

What does this symbol mean?

Answer (score 1):

The symbol is a general warning symbol.  Since the context is charging, it means that

1. It is slow charging. In which case it will tell you how long it will take to charge.  This can be fixed by finding the right combination of charger and cable.
2. There is a problem with charging.  This could mean connector fault or battery fault.  If the battery is removable (not applicable to S9) then remove and re-insert the battery.

Answer (score 0):

Basically that symbol means that the charger that is inserted into the phone is slow charging it. To fix this problem, change chargers.